Stop fan from always/often running on Asus VivoBook, Arch Linux
I recently got an ASUS VivoBook Pro 15 OLED for college, and installed Arch Linux on it (this was my first experience outside of Ubuntu).
It's mostly worked fine - I've got KDE Plasma installed, and I also have TLP for battery management if that's important.
I noticed that the fans seem to be running almost constantly, but it's not a thermal or performance issue - the CPU is not hot at all (<40 C), almost nothing is running and it starts pretty much on boot. This happens both plugged into AC and on battery.
Instead this seems to be a fan control issue, but I'm not sure how to solve it.
I've tried using fancontrol, but it's not able to detect my fan, and I tried using asus-nb-wmi as detailed here, but the files pwm1 and pwm1_enable don't exist.
There don't seem to be any BIOS settings related to the fan, either.
I've tried NBFC as well, but there's no good config for this laptop and trying similar existing ones caused some serious battery management issues.
I initially ran into this problem on a patched (backporting a fix for my keyboard) version of Arch Linux kernel 6.10.3-arch1 but it persisted when I switched to 6.10.6-arch1.
Will I need to do research into how this model of laptop interfaces with its fan and write a config for something, or is there a solution out there that might help?
Thank you!

Is there something similar to Ubuntu's  Settings > Power > power mode > Performace | Balanced | Power Saver in Arch ?  Balanced and Saver modes lessens the fan runs.

@Hannu I'm not sure if there's a direct parallel but TLP gives a handful of different power modes, in my case default performance balance_performance balance_power power. As far as I can tell the problem still happens for all of them though. Also with a very light load the fan probably shouldn't be running even on performance settings? I can post the output of a tlp-stat or other command if that would help.

Sorry, I'm probably not able to help more; maybe google some on Vivo's. I can only guess that it might be  a driver problem. Maybe dmesg | less can reveal something not having a suitable driver?
